# Nested NgFor is not working - Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-template

I am trying to convert my AngularJS application to Angular2 application.I have a nested loop in my template. But it is not working when I use Angular2 syntax.

this is my code -

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor = "let lbusQuestionAnswer of ibusQuestion.ilstQuestionAnswer">
  <table> 
   <tr *ngFor = "let lbusComment of lbusQuestionAnswer.ilstComments">
    <td>
     <div>{{lbusComment.icdoComment.idoComment.commentHtml}}</div>
    </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
 </tr>
</table>
```

JSON 
[image]
And I get below error in console log.

```
EXCEPTION: TypeError: Cannot read property 'ilstComments' of undefined
```

I know, there are a lot of similar questions like this on StackOverflow. But nothing seems to be working.

Thanks
Fahad Mullaji

Comment: Your exception implies that `lbusQuestionAnswer` is `undefined`

Comment: But it is not. Let me add the possible JSON in the question

Comment: I know it is undefined but why is it undefined, when it should have values

Comment: It *should* have values. I suggest you try logging `ibusQuestion.ilstQuestionAnswer` to the console or render it in your view to check the data is indeed there as you'd expect it to be.

Comment: But technically if ibusQuestion.ilstQuestionAnswer does not have values then it should not even go in the nested loop. It will definitely fail.

Comment: I think the object you should check is `ibusQuestion`. Make sure this object has an array for property `ilstQuestionAnswer`

Comment: I have added my JSON response screenshot. Please check and let me know if I am missing anything!!

Answer (score 0):

```
<div *ngIf="ibusQuestion && lbusQuestionAnswer" >
  <table>
    ...
  </table>
</div>
```

Valida si los elementos de la lista existen antes de mostrarlos en la vista

Answer (score 0):

I found solution to this here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/34833436

When I added `<div *ngIf ="ibusQuestion">` then it worked fine!!

I hope this answer helps and explains the real reason behind it