# Angular2 routing issue and ngOnInit called twice

Tags: angular, routes, ngoninit

I'm having a very odd issue with Angular 2 routing to where my `ngOnInit` in the component that I am routing to is getting called twice, and the route in the browser is getting reset to the original route.

I have a `NotificationListComponent` and a `NotificationEditComponent` in a `MaintenanceModule`.

In my root `AppModule`, I setup the `RouterModule` to redirect any unmapped routes to `/maintenance/list`.

**app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      {path: "", redirectTo: "maintenance/list", pathMatch: "full"},
      {path: "**", redirectTo: "maintenance/list", pathMatch: "full"}
    ], {useHash: true}),
    CoreModule.forRoot({notificationUrl: "http://localhost:8080/notification-service/notifications"}),
    MaintenanceModule
  ],
  providers: [NotificationService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

And I have the `/maintenance/list` route defined in my `MaintenanceModule`, which points at my `NotificationListComponent`, as well as a `/maintenance/edit/:id` route which points at my `NotificationEditComponent`.

**maintenance.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      {path: "maintenance/list", component: NotificationListComponent, pathMatch: 'full'},
      {path: "maintenance/edit/:id", component: NotificationEditComponent, pathMatch: 'full'}
    ]),
    FormsModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    NotificationListComponent,
    NotificationEditComponent
  ]
})
export class MaintenanceModule {}
```

When my application loads, it correctly follows the `/maintenance/list` route, and I can see all of my notifications in a list. For each notification in the list there is an edit icon, which has its `click` event bound to the `edit(id: number)` method in my `NotificationListComponent`

**notification-list.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: 'notification-list.component.html'
})
export class NotificationListComponent implements OnInit {

  notifications: Notification[];
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService,
              private _router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this._notificationService.getNotifications()
      .subscribe(
        notifications => this.notifications = notifications,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error);
  }

  clearError(): void {
    this.errorMessage = null;
  }
}
```

**notification-list.component.html**:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Notification Maintenance</h1>

  <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert-box alert">
    <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
    <a class="right" (click)="clearError()">&times;</a>
  </div>

  <p-dataTable [value]="notifications" [sortField]="'code'" [responsive]="true" [sortOrder]="1" [rows]="10" [paginator]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,50,100]">
    <p-header>Available Notifications</p-header>
    <p-column [field]="'code'" [header]="'Code'" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width':'10%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column [field]="'name'" [header]="'Name'" [sortable]="true" [style]="{'width':'40%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column [field]="'roles'" [header]="'Roles'" [style]="{'width':'40%'}"></p-column>
    <p-column [field]="'notificationId'" [header]="'Edit'" [style]="{'width':'10%'}">
      <template let-row="rowData" pTemplate="body">
        <a [routerLink]="'/maintenance/edit/' + row['notificationId']"><span class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></span></a>
      </template>
    </p-column>
  </p-dataTable>
</div>
```

As you can see, the `edit(id: number)` method should navigate to the `/maintenance/edit/:id` route. When I click the icon to navigate to that route, the browser flashes the correct route in the address bar (e.g. `localhost:4200/#/maintenance/edit/2`), but then the route in the address bar immediately changes back to `localhost:4200/#/maintenance/list`. Even though the route returned to `/maintenance/list` in the address bar, my `NotificationEditComponent` is still visible in the actual application. However, I can see that the `ngOnInit` method is being called twice in my `NotificationEditComponent`, because the `id` gets logged to the console twice, and if I put a breakpoint in the `ngOnInit` function, it hits that breakpoint twice.

**notification-edit.component.ts**:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: "notification-edit.component.html"
})
export class NotificationEditComponent implements OnInit{

  notification: Notification;
  errorMessage: string;

  constructor(private _notificationService: NotificationService,
              private _route: ActivatedRoute,
              private _router: Router) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    let id = +this._route.snapshot.params['id'];
    console.log(id);
    this._notificationService.getNotification(id)
      .subscribe(
        notification => this.notification = notification,
        error => this.errorMessage = <any>error
      );
  }
}
```

This appears to also be causing other issues, because when attempting to bind `input` values to values in my `NotificationEditComponent` using, for example `[(ngModel)]="notification.notificationId"`, the value is not being displayed on the screen, even though I can see with the Augury chrome extension, as well as logging the object to the console, that the value is populated in the component.

**notification-edit.component.html**:

```
<div class="row">
  <h1>Notification Maintenance</h1>

  <div *ngIf="errorMessage" class="alert-box alert">
    <span>{{errorMessage}}</span>
    <a class="right" (click)="clearError()">&times;</a>
  </div>

  <p-fieldset [legend]="'Edit Notification'">
    <label for="notificationId">ID:
      <input id="notificationId" type="number" disabled [(ngModel)]="notification.notificationId"/>
    </label>
  </p-fieldset>

</div>
```

Does anyone have any idea why this would be happening?

## Update:

I removed my calls to the `NotificationService`, and replaced them with just some mock data, and then the routing started working! But as soon as I add calls to my service, I get the same issue I described above. I even removed the `CoreModule` and just added the service directly to my `MaintenanceModule`, and still got the same issue whenever I use the actual service instead of just mock data.

**notification.service.ts**:

```
@Injectable()
export class NotificationService {
  private _notificationUrl : string = environment.servicePath;

  constructor(private _http: Http) {
  }

  getNotifications(): Observable<Notification[]> {
    return this._http.get(this._notificationUrl)
      .map((response: Response) => <Notification[]>response.json())
      .catch(this.handleGetError);
  }

  getNotification(id: number): Observable<Notification> {
    return this._http.get(this._notificationUrl + "/" + id)
      .map((response: Response) => <Notification>response.json())
      .catch(this.handleGetError);
  }

  postNotification(notification: Notification): Observable<number> {
    let id = notification.notificationId;
    let requestUrl = this._notificationUrl + (id ? "/" + id : "");
    return this._http.post(requestUrl, notification)
      .map((response: Response) => <number>response.json())
      .catch(this.handlePostError);
  }

  private handleGetError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw('Error retrieving existing notification(s)!');
  }

  private handlePostError(error: Response) {
    console.error(error);
    return Observable.throw('Error while attempting to save notification!');
  }
}
```

And the service seems to run fine - I can see that the endpoint successfully returns data and I can see that the data looks correct when I look at my `NotificationEditComponent` with the Augury chrome extension. But the data does not show in the template, and the route in the URL returns to `/maintenance/list` even though the template for the `/maintenance/edit/:id` route is still displayed.

## Update 2:

As suggested by @user3249448, I added the following to my `AppComponent` for some debugging:

```
constructor(private _router: Router) {
  this._router.events.pairwise().subscribe((event) => {
    console.log(event);
  });
}
```

Here is the output of that when I click on one of the "edit" links:

[image: Route logging]

Comment: Are you using the most recent Angular2 version? There was an issue a while ago that caused this behavior but was fixed a while ago AFAIR.

Comment: Try removing the wildcard route and see if the issue goes away. I remember reading something about wildcard routes needing to be last in the list, and I'm not so sure that is the case in your configuration.

Comment: I'm using **2.4.8**, and `@angular/router` version **3.4.8**. And the issue still occurs, even without the wildcard route.

Comment: Even if I remove the empty route as well, the issue still persists.

Comment: Could you please provide notification-list.component.html code?

Comment: @user3249448 Added it under notification-list.component.ts

Comment: Ok Html looks good. Lets find out how navigation is flowing. we need to register various route change / start / end event which will give us idea and may be the reason about what was the url before navigation. try this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33520043/how-to-detect-a-route-change-in-angular-2/38080657#38080657

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Was finally able to resolve the issue after getting the debugging help from @user3249448.

Turns out I was getting this `NavigationError`, even though no errors were being logged to the console:

[image]

Here was the full stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'notificationId' of undefined
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_NotificationEditComponent0.detectChangesInternal (/MaintenanceModule/NotificationEditComponent/component.ngfactory.js:487:49)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80125:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80320:44)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.internalDetectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80110:18)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.View_NotificationEditComponent_Host0.detectChangesInternal (/MaintenanceModule/NotificationEditComponent/host.ngfactory.js:29:19)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.AppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80125:14)
    at CompiledTemplate.proxyViewClass.DebugAppView.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:80320:44)
    at ViewRef_.detectChanges (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:60319:20)
    at RouterOutlet.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:65886:42)
    at ActivateRoutes.placeComponentIntoOutlet (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24246:16)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24213:26)
    at http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24149:58
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at ActivateRoutes.activateChildRoutes (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24149:29)
    at ActivateRoutes.activate (http://localhost:4200/vendor.bundle.js:24123:14)
```

So essentially, my template was being rendered before the call to my web service was returned, and my template could not be rendered properly because `notification` was `undefined`, so I got this `NavigationError`, which caused the described behavior (doesn't it seem like this error should be logged to the console without having to add extra debugging code in your `AppComponent`?).

To fix this, all I had to do was add an `*ngIf` to my `fieldset` that contained all the information about the `notification`.

```
<p-fieldset [legend]="'Edit Notification'" *ngIf="notification">
```

And now my template loads properly once the data is returned from the web service.

Comment: Free tip, you can also use the elvis operator http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent/34833436#34833436

Comment: Official docs here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator

Answer (score 0):

My guess would be that your browser is interpreting your edit link as an actual link instead of doing what you want it to do. This is based on the fact that you see a flash - sounds like the browser is trying to visit the link in question.

Try changing the item that you click on in your notification list to edit the notification from an anchor tag to a simple span or div. If you don't get the flash, then you know that was your issue.

Comment: Nope, changing to a div didn't work. And it's not the actual page that flashes. The page actually renders the edit template correctly (other than the model not binding to inputs correctly), it's only the address bar that flashes to the correct edit route, then back to the list route, while the edit template remains displayed on the actual page.