# How to access the Json data from a service without data model in Angular

Tags: angular

I have this Nested json that i am getting from my service get call

```
{
    "id": "7979d0c78074638bbdf739ffdf285c7e1c74a691",
    "seatbid": [{
        "bid": [{
            "id": "C1X1486125445685",
            "impid": "12345",
            "price": 0,
            "adm": {
                "native": {
                    "link": {
                        "url": "http: //i.am.a/URL"
                    },
                    "assets": [{
                        "id": "001",
                        "required": 1,
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Learn about this awesome thing"
                        }
                    }],
                    "imptrackers": ["https://trks.c1exchange.com/trk/c?pid=123&et=i&profileid=123&siteid=12345&adslot=AUM&adsize=300x250&imprtype=IMAGE&cpm=0.0&dspcid=834&rndid=368997882&adomain=[c1exchange.com]&urid=8787893965303118897&uimprid=2063341746607836879&urespid=0"]
                }
            },
            "adomain": ["c1exchange.com"],
            "cid": "834"
        }]
    }],
    "cur": "USD"
}{
    "id": "7979d0c78074638bbdf739ffdf285c7e1c74a691",
    "seatbid": [{
        "bid": [{
            "id": "C1X1486125445685",
            "impid": "12345",
            "price": 0,
            "adm": {
                "native": {
                    "link": {
                        "url": "http: //i.am.a/URL"
                    },
                    "assets": [{
                        "id": "001",
                        "required": 1,
                        "title": {
                            "text": "Learn about this awesome thing"
                        }
                    }],
                    "imptrackers": ["https://trks.c1exchange.com/trk/c?pid=123&et=i&profileid=123&siteid=12345&adslot=AUM&adsize=300x250&imprtype=IMAGE&cpm=0.0&dspcid=834&rndid=368997882&adomain=[c1exchange.com]&urid=8787893965303118897&uimprid=2063341746607836879&urespid=0"]
                }
            },
            "adomain": ["c1exchange.com"],
            "cid": "834"
        }]
    }],
    "cur": "USD"
}
```

the problem is i want to use it in my component without having a data model for the same

Presently in my component

```
 ngOnInit() {

    this.weatherService.getPocData().subscribe( res =>  {
      this.openRtbResponse = res.openRtbResponse;

    });

  }
```

and in my template

```
 {{openRtbResponse | json}}
```

I am able to access the same .

But now when i want to access the nested value like this it gives undefined like

```
this.openRtbResponse.seatbid[0].bid[0].adm.native.assets[0].id
```

its throws errors.

Without data model can't i use the json value

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: TypeError: l\_thing0 is undefined in \[{{thing.title}} in AppComponent@4:44\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent)

Comment: I am having the same problem, I managed by sending individual values frOm component in a var to HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Typescript is a superset of Javascript, so anything that's not explicitly typed is of type `any` -- which essentially means it's your "traditional" Javascript object.

You should be able to access those properties without a backing type.  I'm guessing that you're trying to access it too early or the path is wrong, which is giving you the error.

To answer your question directly:  Yes, you should be able to access that.

Comment: yup this is what i felt but i thing as i am using a service for the same i:e a http get call that is creating the issue

Comment: I would just debug/log your way through it.  It's either a pathing issue or a timing issue, I would imagine.

Answer (score 0):

You must call `.json()` on request response like this to have a JSON object:

```
function getPocData() {
    return http.get('friends.json')
               .map(response => response.json());
}
```

Be sure to do it inside your `getPocData()` function from `weatherService`.

Comment: Ok, so maybe you need to use elvis operator: `this.openRtbResponse?.seatbid[0]?.bid[0]?.adm?.native?.assets[0]?.id`, it tells angular not check what is after `?` if previous value is null/undefined