# ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImagesUrl' of undefined

Tags: angular, binding, angular-ng-if, angular2-observables

I am simply trying http fetch the site settings of an app and then to bind a property called "siteConfig.ImagesUrl", it seems to have successfully binded, however also causes the following error:

**ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'ImagesUrl' of undefined
ERROR CONTEXT DebugContext_ {view: Object, nodeIndex: 26, nodeDef: Object, elDef: Object, elView: Object}**

if "siteConfig.ImagesUrl" is removed the errors disappear. Please can someone point out where I am going wrong.

**cart.component.html**

```
<div *ngFor="let product of productCollection; let i=index" class="row">
                        <div class="col-sm-2 product-image">
                            <div class="img-wrapper">
                                <img [src]="siteConfig.ImagesUrl.toString() + product.ProductImageUrl" [alt]="product.ProductShortDescription" /> //<== Error occurs here
                            </div>
                        </div>
</div>
```

**cart.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, Input, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Product } from '../products/product.entity';
import { ICartService, ICartControllerSettings, ICartComponent } from './cart.interfaces';
import { SiteSettingsService } from '../../services/site/settings.service';

@Component({
    selector: 'e-cart',
    templateUrl: './templates/cart.component.html'
})

export class CartComponent implements ICartComponent { 
    tmpCollection: Product[];
    productCollection: Product[];
    CartControllerSettings: ICartControllerSettings = null;
    siteConfig: JSON;

    constructor(private _siteSettingsService: SiteSettingsService) { }

    ngOnInit() {
        this._siteSettingsService.FetchSiteSettings().subscribe((response) => this.siteConfig = response);
    }
}
```

**settings.service.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit, Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, HttpModule, Response } from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class SiteSettingsService {
    siteConfigUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/siteconfig";
    uiConfigUrl: string = "http://localhost:3000/uiconfig";

    constructor(private _http: Http) { }
    public imagePath: string;

    FetchSiteSettings() {
        return this._http.get(this.siteConfigUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }

    GetUISettings() {
        return this._http.get(this.uiConfigUrl).map((response: Response) => response.json());
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: TypeError: l\_thing0 is undefined in \[{{thing.title}} in AppComponent@4:44\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to check before rendering the `ImagesUrl` is `siteConfig` exists..

```
<div class="img-wrapper" *ngIf="siteConfig">
      <img [src]="siteConfig.ImagesUrl.toString() + product.ProductImageUrl" [alt]="product.ProductShortDescription" /> //<== Error occurs here
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

siteConfig can be null so use **?** in the binding to handle that. See the [safe navigation operator](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/template-syntax.html#!#safe-navigation-operator) in the docs for more.

```
<img [src]="siteConfig?.ImagesUrl.toString() + product.ProductImageUrl" [alt]="product.ProductShortDescription" />
```