# Cannot read property 'title' of undefined in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

My component

```
export class MoviedetailComponent implements OnInit {
 movie:any

 constructor(
  private getmovie: GetmovieService,
  private router: Router,
  private rout: ActivatedRoute
 ) { }

 ngOnInit() {
   this.rout.params
   .switchMap((params: Params) => 
   this.getmovie.getMovieById(+params['id']))
   .subscribe(movie => {
    this.movie = movie;
    console.log(this.movie);
 });

 }

}
```

my html

```
<p>{{movie.title}}</p>
```

So when I load the page, it shows the content of movie.tittle, but there is also an error in console saying "Cannot read property 'title' of undefined"

Any ideas?

Comment: And also there is the movie object in console

Comment: I can't see movie.title anywhere in your ts file

Comment: @kirk jonrsharpe these aren't really the best option here.  See my answer.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent dup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `subscribe()` function is asynchronous, meaning the code inside of the callback (including `this.movie = movie`) can be executed after the completion of the `ngOnInit()` method.

As @kirk and @jonrsharpe pointed out in the comments, you could add a test before the value inside of the template.  But this is not the most elegant solution.

I would suggest instead reading up on Observables, and in particular, [the async pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/AsyncPipe).  This makes your code a lot simpler:

```
this.movie = this.route.params
  .switchMap((params: Params) => 
      this.getmovie.getMovieById(+params['id']))
```

and then your HTML would look like:

```
<p>{{ (movie | async)?.title }}</a>
```

Note the `?`- this checks that the title property actually exists, so that an error doesn't occur if the object is invalid.  You should also add a template block somewhere else which handles cases of errors.

Comment: @Kirk - sorry, I realized I made that mistake.  Updated.