# Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined in Angular 2

Tags: angular

Why do I keep on having the error of `Cannot read property 'UserName' of undefined` when I have defined it in my Component. Using the 'elvis operator' in the html code does not do the trick. Please look at my code on where I get this error:

**user.model.ts**

```
export class User {
    UserName: string;
    Password: string;
    Email: string;
    FirstName: string;
    LastName: string;
}
```

**sign-up.component.ts**

```
export class SignUpComponent implements OnInit {

  user: User;

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

**sign-up.component.html**

```
<form class="col s12 white" #userRegistrationForm="ngForm">

<div class="row">
    <div class="input-field col s6">
        <input class="validate" type="text" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.UserName" required  minlength="3">
        <label>Username</label>
    </div>

    <div class="input-field col s6">
    <input type="password" name="Password" #Password="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user.Password"> 
    <label>Password</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row">

</div>

</form>
```

Using the elvis operator:
`<input class="validate" type="text" name="UserName" #UserName="ngModel" [(ngModel)]="user?.UserName" required  minlength="3">`

Comment: So where *are* you expecting the user data to come from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular 2: TypeError: l\_thing0 is undefined in \[{{thing.title}} in AppComponent@4:44\]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34833358/angular-2-typeerror-l-thing0-is-undefined-in-thing-title-in-appcomponent)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39755336/1260204)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seen as though you are using `export class User ...` you can simply do `user: User = new User();`

Comment: This isn't best practice to do since you are using new operator which tightly couples the code. Using User as a service and injecting it in constructor would be the correct way. Please check my answer for detail.

Comment: that isnt the best/correct way, providers are for creating singletons in terms of services, not for interfaces/classes

Comment: If not then how you intend to make a class not tightly coupled with a component. This is about perception my friend :) Please read about inversion of control and dependency injection.

Comment: i never mentioned coupling, and i am not your _friend_

Comment: Well you should consider coupling while writing code. That is the best practice.

Comment: @MdAlamin chance s are, you are doing something wrong/different, this works for me in angular 7

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialise the user object, just assign a new user object

```
user: User = new User();
```

Comment: this wont work as all of the values in the class/interface are required, you would have to assign a base value to each property

Comment: yeah you are right, empty object means new user user object , i should have been more specific

Answer (score -1):

New you'r model at the time of declaring.

**instead of**

```
user: User;
```

**Write**

```
user: User = new User();
```

Best practice for declaring variable as model in angular is to **New** variable at the time of declaration except of sometime.

Comment: this is a copy of other answers

Comment: @mast3rd3mon I didn't copy anything , I wrote the right answer and after it when i saw you wrote the right also I voted up you'r answer bro. anyway it was accidentally. please notice that stack is not a war field , it's just a place for programmers to help each other.

Answer (score -2):

**Although this is not waht you should do as per best practices**

In your model.ts, You can initialize the properties.

```
        export class User 
      {
        UserName: string="";
        Password: string="";
        Email: string="";
        FirstName: string="";
        LastName: string="";
      }
```

**Best** way would be to inject the User into your component.

```
providers:[User]

constructor(private user:User);
```

As prerequisite to this you should decorate your class as `@Injectable()`

Comment: thats bad practice to assign values in the definition file

Comment: Please let me finish the answer before downvoting :)

Comment: providers are for services, not interfaces/classes

Comment: Classes should be used for injection to make it loosely coupled. Provider is for anything which you wish to inject in a component.

Comment: classes should only be used in the constructor injection if they are declared with `@Injectable()`

Comment: Although it wont throw any error but yes per the guideline it should.

Comment: and as the class in this case is being used as an interface and therefore doesnt have `@Injectable()` in the declaration, it _Should not_ be used in the constructor injection

Comment: by your edit, are you suggesting that the interface/class should have the `@Injectable()` in the declaration?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169070/discussion-between-dheeraj-kumar-and-mast3rd3mon).